# Iterate over all files in a directory, or only specified files in sh

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory `config` with the following file listing:

```
$ ls config
file one
file two
file three
```

I want a bash script that will, when given no arguments, iterate over all those files; when given names of files as arguments, I want it to iterate over the named files.

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in ${@:-config/*}
do
    echo "Processing '$file'"
done
```

As above, with no quotes around the list term in the for loop, it produces the expected output in the no-argument case, but breaks when you pass an argument (it splits the file names on spaces.) Quoting the list term (`for file in "${@:-config/*}"`) works when I pass file names, but fails to expand the glob if I don't.

Is there a way to get both cases to work?

Comment: @Jidder Do the filenames you supplied as arguments have spaces in the names?

Comment: Yeah, that's the critical thing, the file names have spaces; passing `script.sh "config/file one" "config/file three"` breaks it without the quotes around the list term.

Comment: @Jidder He is. But unless you quote `"$@"` inside the script, they get split on whitespace in the loop.

Comment: @jidder I already did this. Try it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the processing code in a function, and then use different loops to call it:

```bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then for file in config/*
    do processing_func "$file"
done
else for file in "$@"
    do processing_func "$file"
done
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

For a simpler solution, just modify your IFS variable

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=''
for file in ${@:-config/*}
do
    echo "Processing '$file'"
done
IFS=$' \n\t'
```

The `$IFS` is a default shell variable that lists all the separators used by the shell. If you remove the space from this list, the shell won't split on space anymore. You should set it back to its default value after you function so that it doesn't cause other functions to misbehave later in your script

**NOTE:** This seems to misbehave with dash (I used a debian, and `#!/bin/sh` links to dash). If you use an empty `$IFS`, args passed will be returned as only 1 file. However, if you put some random value (i.e. `IFS=':'`), the behaviour will be the one you wanted (except if there is a `:` in your files name)

This works fine with `#!/bin/bash`, though

Answer (score 2):

Set the positional parameters explicitly if none are given; then the for loop is the same for both cases:

```
[ $# -eq 0 ] && set -- config/*
for file in "$@"; do
    echo "Processing '$file'"
done
```